# Alternar ação de um botão

Tags: java, string, label

Eu andei pesquisando na internet e não achei nada que possa me explicar come eu faço para alternar a ação de um botão em Java...

Exemplo:
Eu tenho um botão que quando eu o aperto quero que ele troque os textos de 2 labels, e quando eu o aperto de novo quero que ele troque novamente os textos... E que ele vá fazendo isso a medida que eu aperto.
Entenderam?
Agora como eu faço isso?

Comment: Se a ação é "trocar o texto de dois labels" então você não está alternando nada, a ação é a mesma toda vez...

Comment: Acho que o ideal é usar o próprio texto dos botões para perceber se tem que trocar de X para Y ou vice-e-versa... é no swing isso?

Comment: Acho que interpretei mal sua pergunta, não é trocar um label com o outro, mas sim trocar ambos por valores independentes, certo?

Comment: Exatamente! :) Quando eu clicar nesse botão quero que ele troque a string do JLabel por outra... Entendeu? @mgibsonbr

Comment: @Dongabi Tendo uma referência pro seu [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html), você tem acesso a métodos `getText` e `setText` para acessar seu texto, tudo o que você precisa fazer é criar um `ActionListener` que use esses métodos (e para alternar entre dois, caso você precise mesmo de duas ações, o modo de fazer está na minha resposta abaixo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo literalmente a pergunta, se você possui duas ações A e B (representadas por implementações da interface `ActionListener`) e você quer alternar entre uma e outra, você pode criar uma terceira classe, genérica, que também implemente `ActionListener` e que execute essa alternância entre as ações. Um exemplo de implementação seria:

```
class Alterna implements ActionListener {
    private ActionListener a;
    private ActionListener b;
    private boolean primeira = true;

    public Alterna(ActionListener a, ActionListener b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    pubilc void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ( primeira )
            a.actionPerformed(e);
        else
            b.actionPerformed(e);
        primeira = !primeira; // Inverte, pra da próxima vez executar a outra ação
    }
}
```

Então basta você criar suas duas ações, normalmente, em seguida criar uma instância dessa classe e atribuir essa instância como ouvinte do botão:

```
meuBotao.addActionListener(new Alterna(a, b));
```

Nota: se por "troque os textos de 2 labels" você quer dizer "passe o texto do label 1 pro label 2 e vice-versa", então você não precisa de duas ações - uma só basta! Mas se você quis dizer "passe o texto do label 1 pra X e do 2 pra Y, no outro clique passe do label 1 pra Z e do 2 pra W", então essa abordagem é uma maneira possível de se fazer.

(outra seria por exemplo usar um `ActionListener` só e implementar a mesma lógica nele)